# Удаление изображения из массива формы

Tags: javascript, jquery, form

Есть код, который выводит изображения, которые были добавлены в `<input>` и там есть кнопка удаления изображения, но у меня никак не получается удалить их из массива формы. Как это можно сделать?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
    $("#files").on("change", function(e) {
      var files = e.target.files,
        filesLength = files.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < filesLength; i++) {
        var f = files[i]
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = (function(e) {
          var file = e.target;
          $("<span class=\"pip\">" +
            "<img class=\"imageThumb\" src=\"" + e.target.result + "\" title=\"" + file.name + "\"/>" +
            "<br/><span class=\"remove\">Remove image</span>" +
            "</span>").insertAfter("#files");
          $(".remove").click(function() {
            $(this).parent(".pip").remove();
          });
        });
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(f);
      }
    });
  } else {
    alert("Your browser doesn't support to File API")
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
      $("#files").on("change", function(e) {
          var files = e.target.files,
            filesLength = files.length;
          for (var i = 0; i < filesLength; i++) {
            var f = files[i]
            var fileReader = new FileReader();
            fileReader.onload = (function(e) {
              var file = e.target;
              $("<span class=\"pip\">" +
                "<img class=\"imageThumb\" src=\"" + e.target.result + "\" title=\"" + file.name + "\"/>" +
                "<br/><span class=\"remove\">Remove image</span>" +
                "</span>").insertAfter("#files");


          }); fileReader.readAsDataURL(f);
      }
    });
}
else {
  alert("Your browser doesn't support to File API")
}
$('body').on("click", ".remove", function() {
var filestoupload = [];

index = $(this).index();
console.log('удаляем файл: ', index)
filestoupload.splice(index, 1);
$(this).parent().remove();
$("#files").val("");
console.log('files to upload: ', filestoupload.length);
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple/>
```

Comment: К сожалению запрос с файлами пустой приходит, если я добавляю 2 картинки и одну из них удаляю.

Comment: как вы принимаете файлы?

Comment: $_FILES и циклом. Если без удаления, то все файлы приходят.

Comment: $_FILES["files"]["name"]; так наверное

Comment: используйте canvas, ajax и formData и все заработает